# Why Cassandra so depend on client local timestamp?

Tags: cassandra, timestamp, consistency

Following case may be logical correct for Cassandra, but difficult for user.
Let's say:

Cassandra consistency level: write all, read one
replication_factor:3

For one record, rowkey:001, column:status

1. Client 1, insert value for rowkey 001, status:True, timestamp
   11:00:05
2. Client 2 Slice Query, get the value True for rowkey 001, @11:00:00
3. Client 2, update value for rowkey 001, status:False, timestamp
   11:00:02

So the client update sequence is True to False, although the update requests are from different nodes, but the sequence are logically ordered.

But the result is rowkey:001, column:status, value: **True**

So why Cassandra so depend on client local time? Why not using server localtime instead client local time?

Because I am using consistency level write all, and replication_factor:3, so for all the 3 nodes, the update sequence is correct (True -> False), they can give a correct final results.

If for some reason, it need strong depends on operation's timestamp, then query operation also need a timestamp, then Client 2 will not see the value True, which happen in "future".

So either using server timestamp or require timestamp for query also (which means, the second step query will not see the result, because the data is in the "future"), it will be more consistent.

Otherwise, the consistency of Cassandra is so weak, even R + W > N.

Comment: From above, I think the reason why you can get value True after step 2 is that Cassandra does inserts based on the sequence not so on the timestamps. Otherwise, you shouldn't have seen the True value, which means that Cassandra doesn't so depend on client local time.

Answer (score 4):

The short answer is that CQL actually does default to server-provided timestamps.

As a longer answer, I wrote a post about the role of timestamps in conflict resolution at http://www.datastax.com/dev/blog/why-cassandra-doesnt-need-vector-clocks.

Comment: What do you mean server-provided timestamps? E.g. my replication_factor is 3, consistency level is write all, then which node's timestamp will be used for one specific record?

Comment: And in your blog, you said **What Cassandra gives up here is the ability to create custom behavior for updates-based-on-existing-values.** But what here want is a causality result, because the new data is already read by client, and based on this, it did a update. Cassandra just fooled by the timestamp (Due to clock drift). So for single column update with strong consistency write, server side timestamp could be better.

Answer (score 1):

CQL uses server side timestamps, but the legacy Thrift interface uses client timestamps.

Note what you describe is not a consistency problem, since all responses will be consistent with each other after the write.  It is a violation of causality though.  Even with server side timestamps, you may get problems with simultaneous writes to the same columns.

A discussion of some of the issues is here: http://aphyr.com/posts/294-call-me-maybe-cassandra

Answer (score 0):

Well cause I had same issue, I will leave this info here, even if it is almost 10 years old :)
It is possible to use server side timestamps.

Timestamps can be assigned by the driver client or the server-side node coordinating the request. All recent versions of the DataStax drivers use client-generated timestamps by default for Cassandra versions 2.1 and later and DSE versions 4.7 and later. Older versions of Cassandra and DSE do not support client timestamps, as they were introduced in the CQL native protocol version 3.

Client-side timestamp generation is the default to keep order of operations predictable from the perspective of a single client. Through monotonically increasing client-side timestamps, the driver ensures that all operations are written in the sequential order that they were executed within the scope of that instance.

Without client timestamps, the client is at the whim of timestamps assigned by coordinating nodes. Coordinating nodes assign timestamps based on their internal system clock. It is difficult to keep the different nodes system clock synchronized in a distributed system. Each node is subject to clock drifts ranging from tens of milliseconds to seconds, even when the nodes use NTP or other clock synchronization software.

Source:
https://docs.datastax.com/en/dev-app-drivers/docs/queryTimestamps.html

So it looks like in case of server-side generation: timestamps assigned at different nodes are not guaranteed to be globally unique. With a steadily high write rate timestamp collision is not unlikely.